# xampp mysql is not allowing me to connect once skip-grant-tables is disabled

Tags: mysql

I am facing strange problem which has started suddenly in EC2 redhat instance. I have my xampp installed in the above mentioned instance.

I am trying to connect to my sql from another EC2 instance

Suppose I have EC2 instance A and EC2 instance B. My instance A has following configuration

1. mysql (as a part of xampp)
2. /etc/hosts has the following entries
   [image]

I am trying to connect mysql from instance B and I am getting following error. Why it is trying to connect ashish.svn.com which is an etc/hosts entry of instance A. Also note that I used to connect same way earlier which used to work and I do not touch the EC2 instance.

[image]

I am getting the following error from windows. I don't know where from this IP address comes (103.56.238.23)? EC2 IP address generally starts with 52 which I have mentioned in my heidisql prompt.
[image]

If I disable **skip-grant-tables** in my.conf file in instance A then it connects to the right mysql server without any issue.

[image]

Note that I already had following configurations in mysql and as mentioned it used to work flawlessly
SET PASSWORD FOR 'xxxx'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'xxxx'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

**I am clueless why it is trying to connect some random IP address (from Windows and another EC2 instance, I noted it here as B) when skip-grant-tables is enabled**

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot, I found the issue. The information_schema database in mysql got corrupted (data got deleted from some of the tables). So I reinstalled mysql and got the problem fixed.